# how can i redirect on another page on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {

        //infinite scrolling is the idea

    }

});
```

```html
<div id="scrollwork" class="scroll-padder">
</div>
```

> This is my div tag. I want to make scroll on homepage and when i scroll down i want to redirect on page work.html with the use of java script

Comment: The JS is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for reply, please give me right JS @alldani

Comment: Welcome! Please see: [ask] | [mcve] | Also check out the [Help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("scrollwork").onscroll=function(){window.location=redirecturl}`